# R: Replace Abbreviations\ Words

Tags: r, gsub, abbreviation

I have tried to resolve this problem all day but without any improvement.

I am trying to replace the following abbreviations into the following desired words in my dataset:

-**Abbreviations:**  USA, H2O, Type 3, T3, bp

- **Desired words** United States of America, Water, Type 3 Disease, Type 3 Disease, blood pressure

**The input data is for example**

- [1] I have *type 3*, its considered the highest severe stage of the disease.
- [2] Drinking more *H2O* will make your skin glow.
- [3] Do I have T2 or *T3*? Please someone help.
- [4] We don't have this on the *USA* but I've heard that will be available in the next 3 years.
- [5] Having a high *bp* means that I will have to look after my diet?

**The desired output is**

- [1] i have *type 3 disease*, its considered the highest severe stage
  of the disease.
- [2] drinking more *water* will make your skin glow.
- [3] do I have *type 3 disease*? please someone help.
- [4] we don't have this in the *united states of america* but i've heard that will be available in the next 3 years.
- [5] having a high *blood pressure* means that I will have to look after my diet?

I have tried the following code but without success:

```
   data= read.csv(C:"xxxxxxx, header= TRUE")
   lowercase= tolower(data$MESSAGE)
   dict=list("\\busa\\b"= "united states of america", "\\bh2o\\b"= 
   "water", "\\btype 3\\b|\\bt3\\"= "type 3 disease", "\\bbp\\b"= 
   "blood pressure")
   for(i in 1:length(dict1)){
   lowercasea= gsub(paste0("\\b", names(dict)[i], "\\b"), 
   dict[[i]], lowercase)}
```

I know that I am definitely doing something wrong. Could anyone guide me on this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would be nice to have a sample of your `data$MESSAGE` to see if our solutions do the right thing. Would you mind attaching the output of `dput(sample(data$MESSAGE, 20))` to your question?

Comment: use `stringr::str_replace_all()` with a named vector for replacing

Comment: Is it possible for one element to contain more than one value? ie could we have a string like `"USA H2O"`?? or each element contains only one value like in the example?

Comment: @teunbrand thank you for the feedback - I have added an example of the input and desired output data on the thread. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to replace only whole words (e.g. `bp` in `Some bp.` and not in `bpcatalogue`) you will have to build a regular expression out of the abbreviations using word boundaries, and - since you have multiword abbreviations - also sort them by length in the descending order (or, e.g. `type` may trigger a replacement before `type three`).

An example code:

```r
abbreviations <- c("USA", "H2O", "Type 3", "T3", "bp")
desired_words <- c("United States of America", "Water", "Type 3 Disease", "Type 3 Disease", "blood pressure")
df <- data.frame(abbreviations, desired_words, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
x <- 'Abbreviations: USA, H2O, Type 3, T3, bp'
sort.by.length.desc <- function (v) v[order( -nchar(v)) ]

library(stringr)
str_replace_all(x, 
    paste0("\\b(",paste(sort.by.length.desc(abbreviations), collapse="|"), ")\\b"), 
    function(z) df$desired_words[df$abbreviations==z][[1]][1]
)
```

The `paste0("\\b(",paste(sort.by.length.desc(abbreviations), collapse="|"), ")\\b")` code creates a regex like `\b(Type 3|USA|H2O|T3|bp)\b`, it matches `Type 3`, or `USA`, etc. as whole word only as `\b` is a word boundary. If a match is found, `stringr::str_replace_all` replaces it with the corresponding `desired_word`.

See the [R demo online](https://rextester.com/BIR73513).